# Indecision on which files to upload on GitHub

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I have a java project made with Eclipse.

While working on a project, Eclipse creates a bunch of files and folders, what folder and files should I upload on GitHub?

I think that everything under the `src` folder should be uploaded. Am I right? Should I commit the .java or the .class files?

Comment: +1 I'm still struggling with this. Some IDEs don't put everything you create in the `src`, such as test cases or makefile. But it seems you have to include the lowest common folder to add to git, which includes a bunch of stuff you don't want. Very quickly things become a mess. [Here's my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833127/how-to-change-directory-of-junit-test-folder-in-netbeans-without-breaking-depend)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

source control such as git are used to commit anything that can be called as source and not environment specific. So code, related resources should go but any IDE specific files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated the question. Please give a look at it.

Comment: @JackScotti commit only the source file and not the compiled file i.e just commit .java and not .class files

Comment: Great, that's what I wanted to know. You win.

Answer (score 3):

Use gitignore either project specific or globally. The easiest way is to create a .gitignore file in your project root repository. For instance

```
# Eclipse
.classpath
.project
.settings/

# Intellij
.idea/
*.iml
*.iws
out/
artifacts/

# Mac
.DS_Store

# Maven
log/
target/
```

Comment: Why would you want to ignore stuff like .project and .classpath? You want to reconfigure your project everytime you check it out?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated the question. Please give a look at it.

Comment: popovitsj that's a matter of taste in a way. I generally tend not to include files that might contain absolute paths or are IDE specific.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which files do you want to share too.

For example, in my current company almost all my colleagues and I use Eclipse, so we have repositoried .project" and .classpath too. It is very handy because changes in .classpath are done only once, and then propagated to all developers.

If your root folder is both the git repo root and your workspace, you won't probably want to upload the .metadata folder, since it contains settings specific to each different developer. And, by all means, you will want to ignore Eclipse's compiled directory (typically /bin).

Think about what do you want to share and/or version, and that will probably give you a list of things to upload/ignore.

**Edit: as said before, upload ONLY .java files, .class files are products of your source code, and have to be generated, not stored.**

Comment: If you use Maven, most settings are updated from there. Then you don't need IDE specific files, because they become derived resources (much like class files).

Comment: If you use Maven, yes, that's true. But Jack didn't mention Maven, as well as we don't use it in all of our projects, and that's why I gave that example earlier. Anyway, the original question has been already solved :)